# Construct a list of integers from bigger to smaller in python

Tags: python, list, foreach, rounding, reverse

I'm attempting to develop a little mouse controller app. It should get (X, Y) coordinates and make the cursor go there.

The problem is that when it attempts going to an X coordinate smaller than the current one.

```
import win32con
from win32api import GetCursorPos, SetCursorPos, mouse_event, GetSystemMetrics
from time import sleep

def clickWithCursor(xDesired, yDesired):
    xCurrent, yCurrent = GetCursorPos()

slope = float(yDesired - yCurrent) / float(xDesired - xCurrent)

def goAhead(x, y):
    for x in range(min(xCurrent, xDesired), max(xDesired, xCurrent), 2):
        y = int(slope * (x - xCurrent) + yCurrent)
        SetCursorPos((int(x), y))
        sleep(0.002)

    mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

return goAhead(0, 0)

def main():
    clickWithCursor(243, 184)

main()
```

Above is just a very bad attempt to do so which does not give me the result I was looking for. I was looking all over how to do it and just could not find the right way.

**In short, I wanna construct a list so it would go logically from bigger to smaller value, or smaller to bigger, according to paramerters order.**

So, if I would give range(4, 1) which I want to be resulted in: [4, 3, 2] or range(1, 4), it would'nt mind and construct it the right way...

***EDIT:***
I refactored the code according to the answers and made it more readable for other users to review. Note the "sequence" method in class MouseController:

```
from win32con import MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP
from win32api import GetCursorPos, SetCursorPos, mouse_event
from time import sleep


class CursorPositionPrinter(object):
    """docstring for CursorPositionPrinter"""
    def print_cursor_pos(self):
        print GetCursorPos()

    def __init__(self):
        super(CursorPositionPrinter, self).__init__()


class AutoClicker(object):
    """docstring for AutoClicker"""
    def click(self, times):

        xCurrent, yCurrent = GetCursorPos()
        for i in xrange(times):
            self.simple_click(xCurrent, yCurrent)

    def simple_click(self, x, y):
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0)

    def __init__(self):
        super(AutoClicker, self).__init__()


class MouseController(CursorPositionPrinter, AutoClicker):
    """docstring for MouseController
    Controlls your mouse magically!!!"""

    def sequence(self, a, b, n):
        mn, mx = a, b
        step = -n if mn > mx else n

        for value in xrange(mn, mx, step):
            yield value

    def click_with_cursor(self, xDesired, yDesired):
        self.go_to_coordinates(xDesired, yDesired)
        self.simple_click(xDesired, yDesired)

    def go_to_coordinates(self, xDesired, yDesired):

        xCurrent, yCurrent = GetCursorPos()

        slope = float(yDesired - yCurrent) / float(xDesired - xCurrent)

        for x in self.sequence(xCurrent, xDesired, 2):
            y = int(slope * (x - xCurrent) + yCurrent)
            SetCursorPos((int(x), y))
            sleep(self.latency)

        SetCursorPos((xDesired, yDesired))

    def __init__(self, latency=0.02):
        super(MouseController, self).__init__()
        self.latency = latency
```

Comment: Hint: `range(4,1,-1)`

Comment: Thanks @NightShadeQueen but I should make my question more clear: the '4' and the '1' would be variables, and we need it to logically know how to construct the list. So if I would give it range(4, 1) or range(1, 4), it would'nt mind and construct it the right way...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`range(a, b, -1 if a > b else 1)`

Answer (score 4):

either go of a step of -1 or 1 depending on which value is greater after you get the min and max:

```
def up_down(a, b):
    mn, mx = min(a), max(b)
    step = -1 if mn > mx else 1
    return range(mn, mx, step)
```

Output:

```
In [9]: list(up_down([4,5,5,7],[0,1]))
Out[9]: [4, 3, 2]

In [10]: list(up_down([0,1],[4,5,5,7] ))
Out[10]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If the min is greater we need a negative step, if not just use a step of 1.

To make it a little more obvious how to use the logic in your own code you simply have to use the if/else:

```
def goAhead(x, y,n=1):
    step = -n if xCurrent > xDesired else n
    for x in range(xCurrent, xDesired, step):
        y = int(slope * (x - xCurrent) + yCurrent)
        SetCursorPos((int(x), y))
        sleep(0.002)
```

If you want to change the step size you can pass whatever `n` you want

Comment: Thanks @Padraic Cunningham but isn't there a cleaner way?

Comment: @TheSilence, the only added code is  `step = -1 if mn > mx else 1`, I used min and max because that is what you are using

Comment: @TheSilence "isn't there a cleaner way?" - a 3 lines function is very concise and elegant (and don't forget: tailor suit to your own *very* specific need!). But hey, if you come up with a better way - please post it here as an answer - I'd love to learn something new!

Comment: You can get shorter, but I suspect not without repeating yourself. `range(mn,mx,abs(mx-mn)//(mx-mn))` comes to mind, but, really, don't do this.

Comment: range(a, b, -1 if a > b else 1)

Comment: @TheSilence, that is what the code is doing but without ramming everything into one line and allowing you to use descriptive names.

Comment: @TheSilence more readable than explicitly stating `step = ...` and using the `step` variable where the `step` arg goes in the function? I think any future reader will see what the code us doing a lot easier as it stands, feel free to unaccept and add your own answer, I don't see any value in adding it here.

Answer (score -1):

```
lim1, lim2 = 10, 2  
step = 1 if lim1<lim2 else -1  
lst = list(range(lim1, lim2, step))  
print(lst)
```

=> [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]

with:
    lim1, lim2 = 2, 10

=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

This form allow:
list(range(lim1, lim2, 1 if lim1

Comment: yes, except for 'min'/'max'. We do not need them. No? And then we can use: list(range(lim1, lim2, 1 if lim1<lim2 else -1)). No?

Comment: Well, yes. min(a) for an integer is strange. No? And so, it's easier to write shorter form: list(range(lim1, lim2, 1 if lim1<lim2 else -1)). No? Just one line. Or more mathematical: list(range(lim1, lim2, ((lim1<lim2) * 2) -1)).

Comment: No. But TheSilence question was about integers. He says: "So, if I would give range(4, 1), I want it to result in: [4, 3, 2]"

Comment: Edit your answer and get the green V ;)